# Using datatable to bind sharepoint list title and internal names to dropdownlist

Tags: sharepoint, drop-down-menu, datatable

I am trying to get the filed names from 2 sharepoint lists and put them into 2 different dropdownlist on a webpart. However, there were some repeating field names in the dropdownlist. I wonder if my code is correct. or is there any other method to achieve the goal?

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("table");

        DataColumn column;
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "Title";
        table.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        column.ColumnName = "Internal";
        table.Columns.Add(column);
 DataRow row;

        foreach (SPField f in importList.Fields)
        {
            row = table.NewRow();
            row["Title"] = f.Title;
            row["Internal"] = f.InternalName;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        ddlImport.DataSource = table;
        ddlImport.DataTextField = "Title";
        ddlImport.DataValueField = "Internal";
        ddlImport.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider Removing hidden field

```
   foreach (SPField f in importList.Fields)
    {
     if (!f.Hidden)
      {
        row = table.NewRow();
        row["Title"] = f.Title;
        row["Internal"] = f.InternalName;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
     }
   }
```